# How do you kill a core.async/thread?

Tags: multithreading, clojure, terminate, core.async

I've got some threads returned by `core.async/thread` involved in some process, which I'm about to shut down. I'm not shutting down my entire program, just these threads. How can I terminate the threads?

The `.stop` method of the Java `Thread` class is deprecated but I'd be happy to use it, except that `core.async/thread` returns not a `Thread`, but a `ManyToManyChannel`:

```
user=> (clojure.core.async/thread)
#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x780e97c0
  "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@780e97c0"]
user=> (type *1)
clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel
```

I haven't found any documentation on `ManyToManyChannel`. That sounds like a strange name for the type of a thread, so there might be something elementary here that I don't understand. But here's my current naïve, nonsensical-sounding question: How do you kill a `ManyToManyChannel`?

`clojure.repl/thread-stopper` seems to have no effect on `ManyToManyChannel`s.

Answer (score 3):

You let the thread terminate naturally. If external termination is necessary, you have to implement it.

```
(defn terminatable [input-ch terminate-ch]
   (thread
     (loop []
       (let [[v ch] (alts!! [input-ch terminate-ch])]
         (if (identical? ch input-ch)
           (if (some? v)
             (do (process-input v) (recur))
             ;; else input-ch has closed -> don't call recur,
             ;; thread terminates
             )
           ;; else we received sth. from terminate-ch,
           ;; or terminate-ch has closed -> don't call recur,
           ;; thread terminates
           )))))
```

Then terminate externally via
    `(close! terminate-ch)`

Finally you can determine when the thread is terminated by taking from the channel returned by `thread`.

I. e.

```
(take! (terminatable (chan) (doto (chan) close!)) 
       (fn [_] (println "Thread is terminated")))
```

Comment: Does this mean that I can't write code like this? `(async/thread (doseq [line (line-seq subprocess-stdout)] (>!! stdout-chan line))` (That is, calling `line-seq` once instead of `alts!!` for every line.) If not, is there some way to get something like the convenience of calling `line-seq` to read everything from the subprocess, and still have an easy way to shut this down without waiting for the subprocess to exit?

Comment: This is the point of stream processing: You model streams with channels. So you'd have to put the lines on a channel, like input-ch in my example, and take one line at a time from it. I. e. `(onto-chan input-ch (line-seq subprocess-stdout))`. Then `v` becomes a line and you can do the further processing like putting it onto the `stdout-chan` within the implementation of `process-input`.

Comment: Consider investing in `pipeline-blocking` and `pipeline-async` as well as transducers, as these provide simple tools to parallilize the processing of your stream. `pipeline-blocking` implements an alternative termination strategy (closing of target channels).

Comment: If all you want to do is putting the lines onto stdout-chan, you can also use `(onto-chan stdout-chan (line-seq subprocess-stdout))` - this process can be terminated by closing stdout-chan. If you don't wish to close `stdout-chan` you create an intermediate channel that puts values onto `stdout-chan` until you close that via `pipe`.

Comment: Much appreciated! I have just happily removed the `(try … catch)`es from around my calls to `line-seq` and replaced them with `onto-chan`. To avoid the complexity of `alts!!`, I replaced each `(loop [] …)` with `(while (not @terminated?) …)`. Each thread is now just 3–4 lines log.

Comment: Could you add a note about closing the output channel of functions like `onto-chan` and `pipeline-blocking` to make them stop even when reading from something like `line-seq`? The documentation for these functions does not mention this, at least not explicitly, and many people would probably find this information useful.

Comment: @BenKovitz They all stop as soon as a put operation returns false because the target channel is closed. It's an implementation to be expected from any such a core process as best practices freeing CPU time automatically in non-deterministic closing scenarios.

Comment: This techinique is slightly less reliable in the same range as your `@terminated` strategy. They both terminate later if the following order of events happen: 1. A value has been put 2. Termination happens 3. The source blocks - It is now up to the source to unblock or produce a value until termination is realized. The implementation I have provided terminates immediately.